# XL2TP hello delay value

Tags: network-protocols

I was trying to test XL2TP 1.3.0 on our MIPS target but got some issue due to constant hello messages. On going thro' the RFC 2661 ; it says that hello delay can be made configurable. But the question lies whether value 0 for hello delay needs to be used or whether the recommended default value of 60 can be set whenever hello delay value is 0.

```
Is XL2TP-1.3.1 is stable ? because there is already a patch on 1.3.1 for hello delay which I can use (again depends on the stability of this patch) ? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like xl2tp doesn't have mechanism to handle 0 delay ; if you configure 0 for hello delay then it takes the time between the hello messages to be sent as 0 and not disable the messages. 0 can be used but with care.

XL2TP has been released officially by xelerence :

```
      https://lists.openswan.org/pipermail/users/2011-October/021086.html
```

Thanks to all .